# Need more details to automate Kiosk mode android app

Tags: android, appium, mobile-application, kiosk-mode, appium-desktop

I want to automate a SOTI KIOSK mode mobile app. I am not familiar with the KIOSK mode app. 
Currently, I am working with Appium for Regular Mobile app (Native app).

**Questions:**

- Can we able to automate the KIOSK mode android app with Appium? if so, could you please provide some details to initiate?
- What are all the Test Automation tools we can use for the KIOSK mode android app?

**Expectation:** Need more details to automate the KIOSK mode android app.

**Actual:** Confusion on supporting test automation tool for KIOSK mode android app

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Muthu Ramasamy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported behavior of Kiosk mode. The whole point of Kiosk mode is to lock down any non-surface level activity, including automation. You cannot access developer settings in  Kiosk mode at all. I have been down this path with my current project and we were told by our device provider that this was not possible.

You have to put the device in admin mode in order to automate it. This is a limitation of `adb`.

Comment: You triggered me the basic ideas. Thank you so much @Christine :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, if you feel like this post helped with your question then feel free to mark it as accepted answer so other users can see that it was helpful.